# CSS selector problem for using and not using `:not()` in same time

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this html code :

```
<div class='input-group has-danger'>
    <input class='form-control' placeholder='first name'> // first name
</div>
<div>
    <input class='form-control' placeholder='last name'> // last name
</div>
```

And i have this CSS code too :

```
.input-group:not(.has-danger):not(.has-success) .form-control:focus{
    border-color: #000;
}
```

First of all i don't want to change html code and my problem is CSS code and i need to resolve the problem with CSS code so lets see what i need.

As you can see we have first name and last name input the important thing is they both are in div element and the first div which has first name input on it has this class : `.input-group` but the second div which has last name input on it doesn't have this class : `.input-group` and the thing which i want is when we focus on inputs the border color of inputs changes to `#000` or something else (color doesn't matter) the problem is my code not gonna select last name and i tried this code :

```
.input-group:not(.has-danger):not(.has-success) .form-control:focus,
.form-control:focus{
    border-color: #000;
}
```

now this is working but its works even on this classes : (`.has-danger`, `.has-success`) which i don't want, the result which is happen after this CSS code is both of inputs are going to `#000` border color after focus, but first name input doesn't have to go `#000` border color because it has this class : `.has-danger` which i tried to block it using `:not()` CSS code.

So what CSS code shall i use? and thanks.

Comment: Not sure I exactly understand what was needed, but input[placeholder="last name"]  would be one way of selecting that input (with variations around it if that isn't unique of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case just replace `.input-group` with `*`:

```css
*:not(.has-danger):not(.has-success)>.form-control:focus {
  border: solid red 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class='input-group has-danger'>
  <input class='form-control' placeholder='first name'>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='form-control' placeholder='last name'>
</div>
<div class='input-group'>
  <input class='form-control' placeholder='a name'>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks and what if the last name is not in any div , can i use `*:not(.has-danger):not(.has-success)` ?

Comment: Oh sorry didn't take this option in account let me update the answer

Comment: don't worry and thanks a lot i will edit your answer i found solution with your help